# Syntax Error executing Create Table

Tags: sql-server

I have a Query I want to run to create a Table users but when executing the query I get this error:    `Started executing query at Line 1
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Incorrect syntax near '`'. 
Total execution time: 00:00:00.031`

This is my Query:

```
    CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `id` int(8) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `login` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  `secret` varchar(16) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `login` (`login`)
);
```

Could anyone let me know why I get this error when running my Query?

Comment: `mysql` or `sql-server`? Did you even know there is a difference?

Comment: create table in `sql server` or `mysql` RDBMS, witch you are using?

Comment: Topicstarter is using SQL-server `Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1` is a SQL-server error message.. MySQL syntax on a SQL-server does not work.

Comment: How did you run this query exactly? Was it from some query tool or grammatically via JDBC/ODBC Driver? Also was it mysql or sql-server?

Comment: I am using an Azure SQL Server

Comment: Then why are you using MySQL syntax?

Comment: This is the syntax I used to create the table for my old database on my MySql server. What should i change then?

Comment: You should change all of that because it isn't even close to the correct syntax for sql server. Just not even close....look at the documentation.

Comment: MySQL and SQL Server is a completely different product.  Read the documentation!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to run MySQL syntax on a SQL-server.

This is the rewritten SQL-Server syntax.

SQL-server does not support backticks (') so i have removed them. 
SQL-server does not support AUTO_INCREMENT instead SQL-server is using IDENTITY. 
 
SQL-server does not support unsigned so i have removed it. 
SQL-server does not support int(8) so ive changed it into int only.

```
CREATE TABLE users (
    id int NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1),
    login varchar(30) NOT NULL,
    password varchar(32) NOT NULL,
    secret varchar(16) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id),
    UNIQUE (login)
);
```

**Edit**

With naming the indexes.

```
CREATE TABLE users (
    id int NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1),
    login varchar(30) NOT NULL,
    password varchar(32) NOT NULL,
    secret varchar(16) NOT NULL,   
    CONSTRAINT PK_ID PRIMARY KEY (id),
    CONSTRAINT UK_login UNIQUE (login)
);
```

Comment: Then consider to accept this answer.. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Comment: Naming your primary key and unique constraint would be even better. Let's learn new people in sql server how to do it correct from the start...

Comment: yes indeed @GuidoG iám more into MySQL database myself.. Naming the indexes/constraints would result in better error messages and better names into query plans.

Comment: MySql does not allows to name indexes like the primary key ?

Comment: Yes it does but the error messages and in the query plans in MySQL are more clear..

Answer (score 1):

I think you are trying to use `MySql` syntax in `Sql Sever`, `Sql server` raise error for using (**`**) character.

use `syntax` of this examples:

**MySQL:**

```
CREATE TABLE Persons (
    ID int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    LastName varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    FirstName varchar(255),
    Age int,
    UNIQUE (ID),
    PRIMARY KEY (ID)
);
```

**SQL Server:**

```
CREATE TABLE Persons (
    ID int NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1),
    LastName varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    FirstName varchar(255),
    Age int,
    CONSTRAINT PK_Person_ID PRIMARY KEY (ID),
    CONSTRAINT UC_Person_LastName UNIQUE (LastName)
);
```

Comment: @Thomas i hope this is helpful for you

Comment: why dont you also name your primary key ?

Comment: your question is "why not using name for primary key?

Comment: No, why do you not give a Name to the primary key. The primary key of this table is not named, which will look bad in any error messages

Comment: much better +1 from me